# django 1.8 makemigrations "No changes detected"

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to understand what I'm missing.

My model before cahnge:

```
class sectorToMapXY(models.Model):
    pos     = models.IntegerField()
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mapX    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    mapY    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    destMap = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='%(class)s_docfile')
```

Model after change (updated the on_delete delete in the destMap):

```
class sectorToMapXY(models.Model):
    pos     = models.IntegerField()
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mapX    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    mapY    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    destMap = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='%(class)s_docfile',on_delete=models.SET(-1))
```

When running `python manage.py makemigrations` it return `No changes detected`.

When changing the `on_delete` to `SET_NULL` or `SET_DEFAULT` it does detect the change.

Update:

I haven't set the SET_NULL nor SET_DEFAULT so when trying to run it returns error (but it detects the change):

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
dashboard.sectorToMapXY.destMap: (fields.E321) Field specifies on_delete=SET_DEFAULT, but has no default value.
    HINT: Set a default value, or change the on_delete rule.
```

When adding the `models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='%(class)s_docfile',null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)` 
running `python manage.py makemigrations` returns to `No changes detected`.

Comment: Please include the output of `makemigrations` when setting `on_delete=SET_ NULL` and `on_delete= SET_DEFAULT`.

Comment: Thank you , I've updated the Q'

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your error on `django 1.8`.

However, I'm not sure how did the `makemigrations` command worked successfully when setting `on_delete=SET_NULL` or `on_delete=SET_DEFAULT`, since you are  missing `null=True` or `default=default_value` on the field definition.

If this is the first time you handle `migrations` on your app, you should run:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations your_app_label
```

As specified [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps).

Comment: After adding the null=True
    `class sectorToMapXY(models.Model):
    pos     = models.IntegerField()
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mapX    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    mapY    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    destMap = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='%(class)s_docfile',null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)` 
The makemigrations returned to detect no changes.